# Найти максимальную разницу между количеством правых и левых узлов бинарного дерева

Tags: python, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Мне нужно найти максимальную разницу между количеством правых и левых узлов бинарного дерева
Например у дерева `tree = Node(None,Node(Node(None,None),Node(None,None)))`
максимальная разница будет у корня: слева 0 узлов, справа 3, значит разница 3

[image: пример 1]

А у дерева `tree = Node(Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(None,None),None)),Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(None,None),Node(None,None))),None),None)))` максимальная разница будет в узле на первом уровне справа (7-1=6)
[image: пример 2]

Мне удалось посчитать разницу правых и левых узлов корня, но я не понимаю, как бы это все рекурсивно прогнать по всем узлам и найти максимальную разницу во всем дереве.

```
from collections import namedtuple
 
def countSide(node):
  if not node:
    return 0
  return countSide(node.left)+countSide(node.right)+1
 
def diff(node):
  if not node:
    return 0
  max = 0
  difference = abs(countSide(node.left) - countSide(node.right))
    
  if difference > max: 
    max = difference
 
  return max

tree = Node(Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(None,None),None)),Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(Node(Node(None,None),Node(Node(None,None),Node(None,None))),None),None))) #6

print(diff(tree))
```

Comment: а в первом случае справа от корня разве не 3 узла?

Comment: @timur да, конечно 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде так должно работать:

```py
def diff(node):
    if not node:
        return 0

    difference = abs(countSide(node.left) - countSide(node.right))
    
    return max(difference, diff(node.right), diff(node.left))
```

Comment: И действительно. Благодарю!